# Open sets in closure of a a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $U\subseteq X$ be open.

If $A\subseteq \overline{U}$ is open in $\overline{U}$.
Then $intA\neq \varnothing$

My attempt:
Suppose $A$ is non-empty.

Suppose $A\subseteq \overline{U}$ is open in $\overline{U}$. That means there exists an open set, $V$ in $X$ such that $A=V\cap \overline{U}$. Note that $\overline{A}\subseteq \overline{U}$.
Hence $intA=V \cap int\overline{U}$.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq \overline{U}$, where $U$ is open and $A$ is relatively open in $\overline{U}$. As you say, we can find some open $V \subseteq X$ such that $A = \overline{U} \cap V$.

Choose a point $x \in A$. Since $V$ is open, and $x \in \overline{U}$, we know that there must exist some $x' \in U \cap V \subseteq A$. Thus, we have
$$x' \in U \cap V \subseteq \operatorname{int} A,$$
proving $\operatorname{int} A \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Note that the metric is irrelevant.